# Why can I connect to both WiFi domain and ethernet internet (different networks), but not Wifi subdomains, domains and ethernet internet?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I'm using Windows 7 and I would like to be able to connect to both my work corporate network (connects to the internet, via wired ethernet), and to the network *and subnet* I am using for testing (does not connect to the internet, via WiFi) at the same time.

I am able to connect to either of these separately, ie, can connect to the internet (wired) by itself and can connect to the test network (wireless) by itself.

Connecting to the test network by itself (WiFi), I can ping and connect to both:

```
specificItem.networkName.companyName
specificItem.subnetName.networkName.companyName
```

However, as soon as I plug in the ethernet connection to the internet, I lose the ability to ping:

```
specificItem.subnetName.networkName.companyName
```

But I can still ping:

```
specificItem.networkName.companyName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Figured this out with help from coworkers; I needed to add the mapping on my laptop to make this work.

Ran a batch file as Administrator including something like this:

```
; This batch file should be run as Admin
route add 10.0.105.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1
route add 10.0.104.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1
```

Then I'm able to use both the internet, network, and subnet at the same time!